# Is it possible to send an email when a person's birthday falls on a certain day of the week?

Tags: scheduled-reminders, civirules

I would like to configure Civi to email someone when a contact has a birthday on a certain day of the week (Sunday, in fact).  The only way I can see is to use CiviRules, but that seems to demand coding to set up the conditions and actions - which I don't want to do.  Using 4.7 but could use 4.6 if that's required. Can anyone help?